# Where can I ask open-ended questions instead?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

GDSE is not a discussion forum—we [discourage](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tour) questions that are *primarily opinion-based* or that *aim to generate discussion*, because they [don't fit the Stack Exchange format](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

However, even if they don't fit here, they might still be *good questions*.

Where could such questions go instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have [a chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development) for that.

In addition, some other large game development sites do welcome open-ended discussion:

- [/r/gamedev](http://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/)
- [TigSource forums](http://forums.tigsource.com/)
- [GameDev.net](http://www.gamedev.net/index)
- [Indie DB forums](http://www.indiedb.com/forum)

You could also ask local game developers [at a meetup](http://www.meetup.com/find/?allMeetups=false&keywords=game+development).